# append to ListData[] in a loop

Tags: java, android

Here we have our `MyListData[]` which contains some list items for our `RecyclerView`:

```
MyListData[] myListData = new MyListData[] {
        new MyListData("Email", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email,"mg",android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email),
};
```

I want to apply my data through a loop, but cant find a way to `.add()` or `.append()` my new values through a while loop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify array size after creation. For such task is better to use collection like [ArrayList](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList). Collections are designed to be dynamically changed. Also your `while` loop will never run as `n > 10` will be false. So the code will look like so:

```
List<MyListData> myListData = new ArrayList<MyListData>();
myListData.add(new MyListData("Email", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email,"mg",android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email));

...
Integer n = 0;
while (n < 10){ 
   JSONObject dump  = reader.getJSONObject(n.toString());
   JSONObject dump2  = dump.getJSONObject("info");
   myListData.add(new MyListData("Email", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email,"mg",android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email))
   n++;
}
```

Also when you know how many iterations needed in advance it's better to use `for` instead :

```
for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  JSONObject dump  = reader.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(index));
  JSONObject dump2  = dump.getJSONObject("info");
  myListData.add(new MyListData("Email", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email,"mg",android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email))
}
```

Last but not least make sure to protect your code from [NPE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Preventing_NullPointerException)

Comment: Thanks, that n variable was a mistake